# Shorthand way of specifying strongly typed values in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, markup-extensions

Here's what I would like to end up with:

```
<Grid Visibility={Binding EnablePurchase, Converter={local:ConditionalConverter TrueValue=(Visibility)Visible FalseValue=(Visibility)Collapsed}}/>
```

Here's currently what I am doing:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Visibility>
        <Binding Path="EnablePurchase">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <local:ConditionalConverter>
                    <local:ConditionalConverter.TrueValue>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    <local:ConditionalConverter.TrueValue>
                    <local:ConditionalConverter.FalseValue>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                    <local:ConditionalConverter.FalseValue>
                </local:ConditionalConverter>
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </Grid.Visibility>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Are you just trying to set the Grid Visibility based on a bool property?  If so why aren't you just using the existing BooleanToVisibilityConverter?

Comment: This was actually just a contrived example. I don't have access to the code at the moment...

Comment: My way of thinking is that I would rather have the code that maps True to Visibility.Visible and False to Visibility.Collapsed inside a custom IValueConverter class that I can Unit Tests against and then in my Xaml I just pass the Bool property to my Converter.  For Enum values you can do stuff like {x:Static ns:EnumName.Value}.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a converter which has properties like this:

```
public class ValueConverterWithProperties : IValueConverter
{
    public int TrueValue { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((int) value == TrueValue)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
<Window x:Class="Converter.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Converter"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <converter:ValueConverterWithProperties TrueValue="5" x:Key="converterWithProperties"></converter:ValueConverterWithProperties>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding item, Converter={StaticResource converterWithProperties}}"></CheckBox>
</Grid>
```

you can also derive from MarkupExtension in your converter for a much nicer usage:

```
public class ValueConverterWithProperties : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public int TrueValue { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((int) value == TrueValue)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then you can set the property directly where you are using the converter allowing you to set different values per converter easily:

```
<Window x:Class="Converter.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Converter"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding item, Converter={converter:ValueConverterWithProperties TrueValue=5}}"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding item2, Converter={converter:ValueConverterWithProperties TrueValue=10}}"></CheckBox>
</Grid>
```